# How to use date() and strtotime() to get a date from a string?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am taking input following Datetime : 12.01.2017 2:25 pm

But while I passed above datetime on php function **strtotime** then it's doesn't returning exact datetime as 24 hours format.

Here is my scripts:

```
  $sdate="12.01.2017 2:25 pm";
  date("d.m.Y H:m", strtotime($sdate))
```

It's returning always **12-jan-2017 14:01:00**

But accurate output should be : **12-jan-2017 14:25:00**

Please let me know how can get accurate datetime.

Thanks

Comment: You got the answer still Recommending you an online tool for strtotime to date conversion:

http://freeonlinetools24.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey there is problem on your dateformat string :
it should be **H:i** instead of **H:m** on your scripts.

Please correct date and format it accordingly your expectation:

```
date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($sdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sdate="12.01.2017 2:25 pm";
echo  date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($sdate));
?>
```

[Output](https://eval.in/714690)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **i** instead of **m** in the date:
like this

```
echo $sdate="12.01.2017 2:25 pm";
echo date("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($sdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers that use `strtotime()`. I would like to show you the `DateTime` class. I find it very usefull and better looking in general. Not that it matters to most people but still.

```
// Date string
$dateString = '12.01.2017 11:03 am';

// Create date object from string
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y h:i a', $dateString);

// Output the date
echo $oDate->format('d.m.Y h:i a');

// Or some other format
echo $oDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Note that `date()` and `DateTime` accept the same date parameters. Your string suggests that you will need the following parameters.

```
d - Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
m - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
Y - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
h - 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
i - Minutes with leading zeros
a - Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem
```

#### More information

For more information about `date`, `DateTime`, `strtotime()` and all parameters you can use:

- [date() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [DateTime - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [strtotime() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

**date() and DateTime manuals list all possible parameters**